# TransactionScope per function for WCF

Tags: sql, sql-server, wcf, entity-framework, transactions

I have two functions for WCF, both are using:

```
using (TransactionScope transactionScope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.Serializable })) 
{
    // Code here
}
```

If I call both functions simultaneously, will one function **always** wait until the other one is finished? I need this for data consistency.

I use SQL Server 2008 and Entity Framework 5.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on what you're doing inside the transaction.

If you are only reading data inside your transactions, there will be no locking conflicts and the transactions won't wait for each other.

If one transaction is reading and the other writing to the same **range of data**, they will have to wait for each other. Same applies to the situation when they both write into the same range of data.

Serializable transaction isolation level is most restrictive of the isolation levels. You can check more here on Microsoft TechNet: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx

Having said all that, you can still control locking on each individual statement level using locking hints. You can read more here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189857(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: Thank you. Both are writing data to the database (and reading too of course). One function's main task is inserting new data, whereas the other function's task is updating the data (based on a certain condition). For example, one is inserting |"A"|"B"|false| and |"A"|"C"|false|. Then the other function can update all entries with "A" (the column with "B" and "C" are not important here) from false to true. I don't want new entries of "A" to be inserted with false when this updates as these should be true as well.

Comment: So that will work fine for you but you need to be sure that the second process doesn't run before first.

Comment: I have no control over the actual order as they can come from multiple clients. I currently coded the first function like this: if there are existing records with "A" AND the records already specify true, then the new records are also at true. The question is what happens when both functions are run simultaneously. Both functions start with the transactionscope mentioned above. In that case, I assume this will work correctly?

Comment: I can't completely understand your logic but yes, the first process will block the other until it's completed. Be careful to not to start both transactions with reading as that may happen at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Both need to start reading so I will design it a little bit different to prevent this from happening.